# Find and Return a word in a string from a list

Tags: r, string

I have the following problem on R: I have a string such as this
string = "Joe attended the university of Harvard"
and a list of names of universities, e.g. list = "Harvard, MIT, Yale,...".

I want a function in R that returns all the words from the list so that, in this case, it would be
f(string, list) = "Harvard"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

Data:

```
str <- c("Joe attended the university of Harvard", 
         "Peter went to Yale", 
         "Sue was at Illinois State")
```

List of universities:

```
unis <- c("Harvard", "Yale", "MIT")
```

Extraction:

```
library(stringr)   
str_extract(str, paste0(unis, collapse = "|"))
[1] "Harvard" "Yale"    NA
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you very much.